# When creating a Bitcoin Farm, how do you evade having 20,000 modems

Tags: mining-hardware

How do you evade having to have 20,000 modems for all the Bitcoin Miners (utilising Antminer S9's)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By using a network switch, like how it's done in the server rooms.

Switches extend the network, allowing more devices to be connected.